# Progress bar, max and reset on 100%

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

Im working on a progress bar connected to XP and MAX XP in sql. On every click on a button you get 1 xp and max xp is 10. I would like so that when a user reaches 100% XP  it should reset back to 0%. And if you have an idea on how to use that "reset" to increase a value of on this case the level of the user should have his current level + 1 on 100% reset.

Im inserting 1 xp every click by this code:

`$sql = "UPDATE progression SET xp=(xp + 1) WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";`

Im creating the 100% xp bar values by making 1 xp = to 10% of the bar from this code:

```
$percent = intval($resultprogression[0]['xp']*100/$resultprogression[0]['max xp']);
```

And im doing the output in html/css by this code:

```
<div class="experience-bar-container">
        <div id="value" style="width:<?php echo $percent ?>%;"></div>
        <h3>XP: <span><?php echo $percent ?>%</span></h3>
</div>


div#value {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   height: 19%;
   background: red;
   left: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging the js code in the console?

Comment: I'd recommend an alternative approach: don't save the progress, but the XP and the current level. Calculate the XP and progress depending on the level after you've queried for the current xp and level.

Comment: @mrksr Why is it a bad idea to save progress also? Currently im saving the level, xp and max xp. Would you mind showing how you are thinking and why it's better ? thanks

Comment: First of all it's somewhat of a convention to let the application do the calculations, not the database layer. That should be for saving and retrieving data, which makes your application easier to understand, debug and more. If you just save xp and current level, you don't ever have to reset anything, just add more xp and levels, which is trivial sql. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use js.
A solution : add a data-attribute to the progress div to store the progress value :

```
<div class="experience-bar-container">
  <div id="value" data-value="<?php echo $percent ?>" style="width:<?php echo $percent ?>%;"></div>
  <h3>XP: <span id="xpPercent"><?php echo $percent ?>%</span></h3>
  <button class="xpButton" id="minus">-</button>
  <button class="xpButton" id="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Then add listeners on your buttons that use the data-attribute value to update the bar width :

```
var progress = document.getElementById("value");
var xpPercent = document.getElementById("xpPercent");

document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newValue = parseInt(progress.getAttribute('data-value')) - 10;
  update(newValue);
});
document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newValue = parseInt(progress.getAttribute('data-value')) + 10;
  update(newValue);
});
```

The "update" function check the progression, and call the reset function if needed which calls the dbupdate function

```
function update(newValue) {
  progress.style.width = newValue + '%';
  progress.setAttribute('data-value', newValue);
  xpPercent.innerText = newValue + '%';
  if (newValue === 100) {
    reset();
  }
}:

function reset() {
  progress.style.width = '0%';
  progress.setAttribute('data-value', 0);
  xpPercent.innerText = '0%';
  dbUpdate();
}

function dbUpdate() {
  // do Ajax stuff to update user's level
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qpg7t603/1/

If you don't plan to support IE10 you should have a look at the progress tag : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Progress